# background color covers text in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, styling

I am making a web site and using Bootstrap. I made the background color blue and now i cant read any text (`<h1>`, `<p>` etc) My `<img>` are all there (not affected by background color)

this is my css

```
body{
        background: rgb(40,40,40);
    }
```

Comment: Probably the color of the text is too close to the background color and there's not enough contrast. Also, `rgb(40,40,40)` is not blue, that's a dark color.

Comment: anyone voting to close, consider for a second that this person is new. take time to help them formulate a more clear question.

Comment: can you show us a screenshot or include a link so we can help troubleshoot

Comment: @JGallardo maybe this person should take the tour of the website and read the help section before ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are not wrong. but still, it helps to be kind and give them a little information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always change the color of your text to a lighter color to get a better contrast with the dark background color, for example:

```
body {
    background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: yes it turned out it was color in body..i changed it to white and now all is good.  my thanks to those who actually tried to  help

Comment: Glad I could help :) can you please accept my answer then?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should first check if you didn't change the color somewhere in your CSS. for example: `body{ color: rgb(40,40,40);}`
If that's not the case, you can just put:`body{color: black;}`